# Outlook Add-In AppointmentItem :: Why is it *always* an OlRecurrenceState.olApptMaster?

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm trying to determing if a modified recurring AppointmentItem's `RecurrenceState` is an `OlApptMaster`, `OlApptException`, or `OlApptOccurence`.

I've created the recurring appointment without difficulty, and when I modify one of the "not-first-in-series" appointments it triggers the `Modified` event handler, but upon inspection its `RecurrenceState` property is *always* `OlApptMaster`.

Shouldn't the first instance be the `OlApptMaster` and following instances be `OlApptOccurence` or `OlApptException`?  If it's always returning the master, how do I get the one that was modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following MSDN Q&A:

**[Outlook's Handling of Recurring Appointments](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/office/en-US/7cf53a74-9d84-4749-8c2b-e6c43e34efb5/outlooks-handling-of-recurring-appointments)**

I quote few points:

> • You get an occurrence by calling GetOccurrence().
>
> • You are responsible for calculating the date/time of whatever recurrence you want, using the pattern for the calculation
>
> • You also have to check the Exceptions collection for deleted instances and exceptions. You do that if GetOccurrence() fails.

So it looks you should be able to find it inside exceptions.

[Similar resource from the same author.](http://computer-programming-forum.com/1-vba/79e926922a1e6171.htm)

And also see [working code sample](http://codes-sources.commentcamarche.net/source/51790-outlook-ical-exporter) (download `calitem.vb` there) to find how they are able to find and handle `OlApptOccurence` in their processing.

**If you are searching for modified occurrence, search it among Exceptions.**

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with the GetOccurrence() method, and finding an exception... but I was under the (mistaken) impression that if you changed an occurrence, that the occurrence would be the item that fired the event, not the master.  What I really need is how to deduce the occurrence that was actually changed.

Comment: @ScottSEA – Modified occurrence is actually the exception. Try create it through Outlook user interface and then inspect the data to understand.

Comment: When I modify a recurrence, I get an exception in the Exceptions collection just like you'd expect - but when I *delete* a recurrence, the Exceptions collection is empty.  Help?

Comment: @ScottSEA – That is correct. Let's have AppMaster for 5 occurrences:  `M`→`1;2;3;4;5`. Modify 3rd one: `M;E3mod`→`1;2;E3mod;4;5`. Now,delete `E3mod` (what you said), you get: `M`→`1;2;3;4;5`. So yes, upon deletion of modified recurrence, it is gone from exceptions storage (it was stored there). If you deleted 3rd occurrence from user's viewpoint (=occurrence `3` missing from sight), it would look like `M;E3del`→`1;2;E3del;4;5`, user sees `1;2;4;5`. Does this make sense? As I said, good help can be preparing the data through user interface, then analyzing them.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that occurrences do not physically exist (think of an appointment with no end date). The exceptions are stored as attachments on the master appointment, never as standalone items. So it makes total sense that you get a change notification for the item that actually changes - the master appointment.

Comment: so I have an item.changed event that will always fire for the master appointment, regardless of which occurrence was changed.  How can I deduce which occurrence was the occurrence that was modified?

Comment: Which exact event do you mean? Items.ItemChange? It only fires for the master appointment (since it is the only one that physically exists). Appointment.Write / AfterWrite events will fire for the occurrence.

Comment: Yes, Items.ItemChange is what was subscribed to....

`Appointment.Write ... will fire for the occurrence`  -- ah!  thanks!